# Why doesent changes the displayed Text, if the String in the Text widget changes?

Tags: flutter, dart

im trying to build a Switch Widget witch changes the displayed Text. Therefore i have the Class with the Switch Widget:

```dart
class SwitchWidget extends StatelessWidget{

  static bool switchOn = false;

  void _onSwitchChanged(bool value) {   
      switchOn = false; 
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Switch( 
              onChanged: _onSwitchChanged,  
              value: switchOn,  
            );
        }
}
```

**switchOn** says if the Switch is On or not.

Then i have the Widget witch puts the text of the my String text to "ON" if switchOn is true and to "OFF" if its false:

```dart
class SwichTextWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  static String text = "OFF";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    if (SwitchWidget.switchOn == true){
      text = "ON";
    }
    else{
      text = "OFF";
    }
  }  
}
```

In another class i now use my Widgets:

```dart
class MatrixPageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    ...
    Row( children:[
            Text("  Clock Mode"),
            SwitchWidget(),
            Text(SwichTextWidget.text),
            ]//Row children
          )
```

but if i use my Switch the text stays at OFF. I expected, that it wouldnt work like this, but whats the easiest way to make it work? 
Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter way of doing that would be like that:

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool switch = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SwitchListTile(
        title: Text('Clock Mode'),
        value: switch,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            switch = value;
          });
        },
        secondary: Icon(Icons.access_time), // or Text(switch ? "ON" : "OFF") instead of an Icon
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm, if i try it like that i get a error in my emulator instead of the app. it says "No Material widget found. ListTile widgets require a Material widget ancestor."
And the second problem is, with this State class i dont know how to bring it into my MatrixPageOne class

Comment: You can add this class like a normal stateless widget. Lets say you have a Column widget in Scaffold body. Column(children:[MyStatefullWidget]) Wrapping it with Scaffold should fix the material error too.

Comment: Hmm, if i add it like this:

`Row( children:[
            Text("  Clock Mode"),
            _SwitchState,
            ]
          )
        ),`
it says "The element type 'Type' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'"

Comment: ohh i think i got my mistake, i need the Widget-Class and not the State-Class in my Page. Sounds kinda obvious after finding it out ^^

Comment: But sadly nothing is visible if i add the MyStatefulWidget to my Column

Comment: ok the problem was caused, because of too vew space in the Container, now everything works, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`_onSwitchChanged` of `SwitchWidget` has the value set to `false` irrespective of the passed value :

```
void _onSwitchChanged(bool value) {   
      switchOn = false; 
    }
```

Change it to :

```
void _onSwitchChanged(bool value) {   
      switchOn = value; 
    }
```

And the text will change.

Comment: Ah yea the change is nessecary but it still doesnt changes the text